# URL not opening on UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I try to open a webpage with a IBAction

```
@IBAction func Start(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.viewWebpage("http://www.xxxxx.xx")
}

func viewWebpage(webpage: String)
{
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(webpage)
    println(webpage)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    self.viewPage.loadRequest(request)
   // self.viewPage.reload()
}
```

The webpage i try to open works when i change in the function the the url to

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.xxxxxx.xx")
```

Where is my mistake? The println() prints out the wright url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with:

```
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(webpage)
```

You are converting the web url to file system url (url of a file contained in the system itself). So it won't work, you need to change that to:

```
let url = NSURL(string: webpage)
```

According to [NSURL Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:)

> `+ fileURLWithPath:`
>
> Initializes and returns a newly created NSURL object as a file URL
>   with a specified path. Declaration
>
> **Swift**
>
> `class func fileURLWithPath(_ path: String) -> NSURL?`
>
> **Objective-C**
>
> `+ (NSURL *)fileURLWithPath:(NSString *)path`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *path*
>
> The path that the NSURL object will represent. path should be a valid
>   system path. If path begins with a tilde, it must first be expanded
>   with stringByExpandingTildeInPath. If path is a relative path, it is
>   treated as being relative to the current working directory.
>
> Passing nil for this parameter produces an exception.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> An NSURL object initialized with path.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method assumes that path is a directory if it ends with a slash.
>   If path does not end with a slash, the method examines the file system
>   to determine if path is a file or a directory. If path exists in the
>   file system and is a directory, the method appends a trailing slash.
>   If path does not exist in the file system, the method assumes that it
>   represents a file and does not append a trailing slash.
>
> As an alternative, consider using `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:`, which
>   allows you to explicitly specify whether the returned NSURL object
>   represents a file or directory.